# cambiar nombre archivo agregar fecha

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo este codigo :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Tarifa.txt');
```

necesito cambiar el nombre del archivo + fecha actual

algo asi pero no me funciona:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Tarifa_" . date('d-m-y') . ".txt');
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error a la hora de manejar las concatenaciones de tu `string` (con las comillas). Prueba con algo como:

```
header('"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Tarifa_' . date('d-m-y') . '.txt"');
```

Si te fijas, en este trozo de tu `string` aperturas con comilla simple, pero cierras con comillas dobles:

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Tarifa_"
```

Y en este aperturas con comillas dobles, pero cierras con simples:

```
".txt'
```

Comment: no funciona: Error del servidor!: Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud o ha habido un fallo en la ejecución de un programa CGI.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Mostrar el contenido de un *.txt*?

Answer (score -1):

vale gracias ya lo he corregido es asi:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Tarifa_' . date('d-m-y') . '.txt');
```